# Identify a column by header and paste data into the matched columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets with columns Line, Number, Date 1, Date 2, Date 3, Date 4, Date 5 and Date 6 in both. What I am doing here is matching the line and number in sheet 2 to the line and number in sheet 1 and then copying the respective dates where there is a match.

```
Sub CopyDatesT()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")      'Sheet we are going to copy results into
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")      'Sheet we are going to copy results from
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    
    'Identify the columns to use in the sheet we are copying into
    ws1SONum = "B"         'Is the column with the first part of our lookup key - the unique id
    ws1SOLine = "C"           'Is the column with the second part of our lookup key - the line id
    ws1AckDate = "X"       'Is the column we want to put the found value into
    ws1DelDate = "R"
    ws1ReqDate = "S"
    ws1OriProDate = "Q"
    ws1ProDate = "O"
    ws1SchDate = "V"
    
    
    ws1SORow = 5              'The row we want to start processing first, we can calc the last row automatically
    ws1EndRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    
    
    'Identify the columns to use in the sheet we are copying from
    ws2SONum = "A"         'Is the column with the first part of our lookup key - the unique id
    ws2SOLine = "C"           'Is the column with the second part of our lookup key - the line id
    ws2AckDate = "D"        'Is the column we want to copy the value from
    ws2ReqDate = "E"
    ws2OriProDate = "F"
    ws2ProDate = "G"
    ws2SchDate = "H"
    ws2DelDate = "I"
    
    ws2SORow = 2              'The row we want to start search first, we can calc the last row automatically
    ws2EndRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    
    'iterate through search terms
    For i = ws1SORow To ws1EndRow        '
        searchKey = ws1.Range(ws1SONum & i) & ws1.Range(ws1SOLine & i)
        
         'if we have a non blank search term then iterate through possible matches
        If (searchKey <> "") Then
            For j = ws2SORow To ws2EndRow
                 foundKey = ws2.Range(ws2SONum & j) & ws2.Range(ws2SOLine & j)
                  
                  'if we have a match then copy the result and end this search (so we will take the first match found only)
                 If (searchKey = foundKey) Then
                    ws1.Range(ws1AckDate & i).Value = ws2.Range(ws2AckDate & j).Value
                    ws1.Range(ws1ReqDate & i).Value = ws2.Range(ws2ReqDate & j).Value
                    ws1.Range(ws1OriProDate & i).Value = ws2.Range(ws2OriProDate & j).Value
                    ws1.Range(ws1ProDate & i).Value = ws2.Range(ws2ProDate & j).Value
                    ws1.Range(ws1SchDate & i).Value = ws2.Range(ws2SchDate & j).Value
                    ws1.Range(ws1DelDate & i).Value = ws2.Range(ws2DelDate & j).Value
                    Exit For
                 End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

This my code where I copy specific columns from Sheet2 and paste it into Sheet1 and it works properly. The problem here is that I am giving the column value into which the data should be pasted. The columns could change over time and it is uncertain, therefore I want to paste data into columns where the header matches to the specified value given.

```
Set rng1 = Range("B4:AS4").Find("Date1")
                If rng1 Is Nothing Then
                  MsgBox "Column was not found."
                 Exit Sub
                End If
  

    
    Set rng2 = Range("A4:AS4").Find("Date 2")
                If rng2 Is Nothing Then
                  MsgBox "Column was not found."
                 Exit Sub
                End If
    
    
    Set rng3 = Range("A4:AS4").Find("Date 3")
                If rng3 Is Nothing Then
                  MsgBox "Column was not found."
                 Exit Sub
                End If
    
    
    Set rng4 = Range("A4:AS4").Find("Date 4")
                If rng4 Is Nothing Then
                  MsgBox "Column was not found."
                 Exit Sub
                End If
    
    
    Set rng5 = Range("A4:AS4").Find("Date 5")
                If rng5 Is Nothing Then
                  MsgBox "Column was not found."
                 Exit Sub
                End If
    
    
    Set rng6 = Range("A4:AS4").Find("Date 6")
                If rng5 Is Nothing Then
                  MsgBox "Column was not found."
                 Exit Sub
                End If
```

This is what I have tried to do to get the columns with the names I have mentioned. But I don't know how to copy the values from Sheet2 into the selected columns now.

```
rng1.Offset(i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2AckDate & j).Value2
                    rng2.Offset(i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2ReqDate & j).Value2
                    rng3.Offset(i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2OriProDate & j).Value2
                    rng4.Offset(i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2ProDate & j).Value2
                    rng5.Offset(i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2SchDate & j).Value2
                    rng6.Offset(i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2DelDate & j).Value2
```

I tried doing something like this but the values being copied are inaccurate. I want it to loop through the values like I am doing previously but I am not sure how to go about it.

I am not very good at VBA and I am just getting started so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to compute all the required column numbers before the main algorithm and store them in arrays:

```
Sub CopyDatesT()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim ws1SORow As Long, ws1EndRow As Long, ws2SORow As Long, ws2EndRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim searchKey As String, foundKey As String

Dim aKeys As Variant, aHeaders As Variant
Dim inKeys As Variant, outKeys As Variant
Dim inHeaders As Variant, outHeaders As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")      'Sheet we are going to copy results into
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")      'Sheet we are going to copy results from
Rem Get indexes of columns by names:
    aKeys = Array("Line", "Number")
    aHeaders = Array("Date 1", "Date 2", "Date 3", "Date 4", "Date 5", "Date 6")
    inKeys = getIndexes(ws2.Rows(1), aKeys)
    outKeys = getIndexes(ws1.Rows(4), aKeys)
    inHeaders = getIndexes(ws2.Rows(1), aHeaders)
    outHeaders = getIndexes(ws1.Rows(4), aHeaders)
    
Rem Then the same code that you had, but referring to cells by column numbers
    ws1SORow = 5              'The row we want to start processing first, we can calc the last row automatically
    ws1EndRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    ws2SORow = 2              'The row we want to start search first, we can calc the last row automatically
    ws2EndRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

   'iterate through search terms
    For i = ws1SORow To ws1EndRow        '
        searchKey = ws1.Cells(i, outKeys(0)) & ws1.Cells(i, outKeys(1))
         'if we have a non blank search term then iterate through possible matches
        If (searchKey <> "") Then
            For j = ws2SORow To ws2EndRow
                 foundKey = ws2.Cells(j, inKeys(0)) & ws2.Cells(j, inKeys(1))
                  'if we have a match then copy the result and end this search (so we will take the first match found only)
                 If (searchKey = foundKey) Then
Rem It's a little easier here than it used to be
                    For k = LBound(inHeaders) To UBound(inHeaders)
                        ws1.Cells(i, outHeaders(k)) = ws2.Cells(j, inHeaders(k))
                    Next k
                    Exit For
                 End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The work of compiling arrays of indices is performed by the following function:

```
Function getIndexes(toSearch As Range, aValues As Variant) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim var As Variant
Dim aRes As Variant
    ReDim aRes(LBound(aValues) To UBound(aValues))
    For i = LBound(aValues) To UBound(aValues)
        var = Application.Match(aValues(i), toSearch, 0)
        If Not IsError(var) Then
            aRes(i) = var
        Else
            MsgBox "Column '" & aValues(i) & "' was not found in " & toSearch.Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
            End
        End If
    Next i
    getIndexes = aRes
End Function
```

Comment: So the column names in both the sheets are different so I modified your code a bit. I am not getting any error but I am not getting any result either. I am attaching the code down below.

Comment: inKeys = getIndexes(ws2.Rows(1), bKeys)
    outKeys = getIndexes(ws1.Rows(4), aKeys)
    inHeaders = getIndexes(ws2.Rows(1), bHeaders)
    outHeaders = getIndexes(ws1.Rows(4), aHeaders)

Comment: `aKeys` and `bKeys` is equal? So, you can delete one of them. About "rows of headers" - I took the values ​​"1st row of Sheet2" and "4th row of Sheet1" from your code and they are not causing problems (otherwise you will get a "Column not found" message). I don't see yet what the problem might be.

Comment: Just made a few changes to the keys and I got the output required. Thank you so much!